# Cannot find module for pre-built browserify package in react-native

Tags: browserify, react-native

I am building an application using react native and the code depends on a third party library which only offers pre-built browserify bundle.

It works fine in the browser,  but when I am using it in react native,  it is throwing error as cannot find module .

I think it might be some piece of code which cannot work in react native but can work in browser but with the error I cannot figure it out.

Is there a solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: what is this library?

Comment: Well, this is a third party library of kore Web sdk. It is available as a pre-built bundle but not as npm source.